# Why does printing the error from net.Interfaces crash my program?

Tags: pointers, go, interface, null

I'm trying to get a list of system interfaces on my machine, I'm using the net package, which is [defined here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interfaces).

I have this tiny little snippet of code, which crashes when trying to print out the error, and I can't figure out why the error is sigsev'ing on me. It's supposed to return an error, or nil right?

I've ran this code with sudo, root and under a regular user account thinking it might be a permissions thing for the network interface, but it persists amongst all user levels.

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var err error
    var interfaces []net.Interface
    var ifString []string
    
    interfaces, err = net.Interfaces()

    fmt.Printf("%v",interfaces)

    if err != nil {
        for _, v := range interfaces {
            ifString = append(ifString, v.Name)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        ifString = append(ifString, "unable to get system interfaces")
    }

}
```

Program output is as follows when running `go build` and executing it:

```
[{1 65536 lo  up|loopback} {2 1500 eno1 b8:cc:3c:8e:d4:d3 up|broadcast|multicast} {9 1500 tun0  up|pointtopoint|multicast}]
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x4a5269]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
/home/andrew/interface/borked.go:20 +0x269
```

Comment: Just print `err`, the `fmt` package will recognize it's an `error` and will automatically call its `Error()` method. As a plus, it doesn't panic if `err` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving a nil pointer dereference because that's exactly what you're doing.

Given the following if statement in your code:

```
    if err != nil {
        for _, v := range interfaces {
            ifString = append(ifString, v.Name)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        ...
    }
```

The `else` is reached when `err` is nil. Yet you are attempting to access a field in it: `err.Error()`, dereferencing a nil pointer.

You need to invert your `if` statement, it's the wrong way around.

Comment: Ack I just realized that  when I was following the program logic.. uggh for shame.. I meant if err == nil